# Deleting the last element of a single-linked-list is not working

Tags: java, list, element

I have a Single-Linked-List and I just want to delete the last element of that list. I checked it, and it doesn't work. I don't know why.

Check out my code (P.S. I want a **recursive** solution):

```
// Delete Last Element
public void deleteLast(){

    if(head == null){
        return;
    }

    if(head.next == null){
        head = null;

    }else{
        deleteLast(head.next);
    }
}

private void deleteLast(ListElement head){

    if(head == null){
        return;
    }

    if(head.next == null){
        head = null;
    }else{
        deleteLast(head.next);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`head = null` just sets the local `head` variable to `null`, not the object in the linked-list it's referencing, you need to do something like:

```
private void deleteLast(ListElement head)
{
    if (head.next.next == null)
        head.next = null;
    else
        deleteLast(head.next);
}
```

You'll notice I also removed your `if (head == null)` check, I believe it's not required.

**EDIT:** Another way to do it:

```
// returns whether we should delete the passed in parameter
private boolean deleteLast(ListElement head)
{
    if (head.next == null)
        return true;
    else if (deleteLast(head.next))
        head.next = null;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: gosh, it works xD... awesome! Thx alot. But is there no way to do it without next.next? i dont like how it looks :P

Comment: @user2252902 Glad I could help. Remember to [accept this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168143/206447) if it solved you problem.